# Android Fragment Behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments

I  have a doubt related to fragment. I have created  one project which contains fragment(3). 
I am using viewpager for swiping from one fragment to another. When I go from one fragment (2) to anther (3) it will not add an item to list but when I go from 3 then 2 then 1 and returns back it will add that item. What is reason behind this. I just want to update my fragment when I go from one fragment to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is because of [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

The value by default is 1. and it cannot be 0.

when the vaule of setOffscreenPageLimit is default i.e 1, one page on both sides of the fragment will be loaded. So when you change data from B and then go to C, C was already loaded.. so changes are not reflected. On the other hand if you change data from B and then go to A, C will be unloaded. now if you go to B then C gets loaded and vaules refresh. Hope i could explain whats happening here..

**When you swipe between two pages, there is a Point when both pages need to be visible, since you cannot swipe between two things when one of those does not even exist at that point.**

also from comment (how to use it) : `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` \will load 2 fragments on both sides of current fragment. by default the value is 1. (this is not the ans to your question though)

Edit :

actualy what i am doing is. in my fragment A or B there are lists. and for every item onclick there is an activity for details. when i open details for any item(i.e in new activity) there i can add/modify data(changes are reflected in db). Now when i press back i.e finish activity and return to main activity with fragments A B and C.. on Resume is called for all fragments. in my fragment C's on resume i called notifyDataSetChanged to my adapter.. so everythime onResume is called. the list in C is updated.

i am not sure if its a good solution, but it works for me.

Comment: how to use it ... I have not used it.

Comment: I answered for "What is reason behind this."and ans for " I just want to update my fragment when I go from one fragment to another." it is tricky to say. i have a kind of hack in my project. i can tell if you want to know.

Comment: are you changing/adding data from the fragment or some activity started by fragment?

Comment: actaully I have changed my design. You are sure that value can't be  zero.

Comment: yes i am sure about it. cannot be 0. try it and it will give error.

Comment: but not solving my issue also.

Comment: you should be getting a warning about this in LogCat, something like:`Requested offscreen page limit 0 too small; defaulting to 1`

Comment: and i have spend a day trying to figure out how to make it work.and the edit in my ans was the best i could do to solve my problem. maybe if you have something similer it will work. **more info is requied to conclude anything else**

Answer (score 0):

Set OffScreenPage limit value. In your case You have 3 Fragments then You have to set the value = 3 .  Therefor when you come back to fragment will be retained.

Comment: You have not understood my question I dont want to retaianed but want update my fragment. When I go from one to anther.

Answer (score 0):

Your viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(3) here 3 is nothing but the number of fragments